# excel VBA permission denied error 70

Tags: excel, vba

i have this simple code

```
Do
If passTime - currentTime > TimeSerial(0, 0, 20) Then GoTo Reset
If Sheet8.IE.document.getElementsByTagName("font")(0).innerText = "Successful" Then _
checkExist = 1 Else checkExist = 0
Loop Until checkExist = 1
DoEvents
```

Which check for the existance of

```
<font color="blue">Successful</font>
```

But the problem is it occasionally gives me permission denied Error 70 and highlighting the code

```
If Sheet8.IE.document.getElementsByTagName("font")(0).innerText = "Successful" Then _
```

which return a result checkExist = 0 when i hover over it,
can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unclear on how the worksheet referenced by the *Sheet8* codename is the parent of an Internet.Explorer object.

Comment: @Jeeped  - you can embed a WebBrowser control on a worksheet.  That control uses IE to show the content.